# What is the appropriate punctuation to indicate the final phrase applies to both of the preceding requirements?

Tags: punctuation, orthography

What is the appropriate punctuation to indicate that the phrase "or agency-recognized equivalent" refers to both  *instruction* and *examination* in the following phrase?

> X has successfully completed Y instruction and passed the Z examination or agency-recognized equivalent.

Comment: Just add an *s* to make it *equivalents*. Or spell it out as "agency-recognized equivalent instruction and examination"

Answer (score 4):

No amount of punctuation can indicate that, because "instruction ... and examination" is not a single phrase: "instruction" is the direct object of "completed", and "examination" is the direct object of "passed". So you can't coordinate them both with the noun-phrase "agency-recognized equivalent". You'll need to rephrase. Perhaps

> ... has either successfully completed ... instruction and passed the ... examination, or else completed an agency-recognized equivalent ...

?

Comment: That's right. Better to split things up and not try to get too much information in one single sentence. In simple sentences, punctuation can help; in complex ones, it's a minefield.